# OidcClient.LoginAsync in Xamarin Android caching the login information

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, openid-connect, identify

In Xamarin.Forms application, I am doing login through OidcClient, I am facing one issue with Android. After the first successful login, the user does not go through the login again. When oidcClient LoginAsync gets called it automatically approves the user. Probably it is caching the login information in the browser. I don't want that, User should always go through the whole login process again. It is behaving perfectly in iOS.

```
            LoginRequest request = new LoginRequest();
            var cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
            request.FrontChannelExtraParameters.Add("prompt", "login");
            var result = await oidcClient.LoginAsync(request, cancellationToken.Token);
```

Comment: I think that the login info might be stored in the cookies of the system browser. The is a CookieManager on Android. I would create a DependencyService for Android where I can have access to the CookieManager. Call the dependency service to clear the cookies right after login. CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookie(); - This would be in the Android implementation of your DependencyService.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I tried that it didn't work. actually, the cookieManager is not returning anything.

Comment: Do you mean that CookieManager.Instance is null?

Comment: Inside CookieManager HasCookie is false. When I am creating cookies from the application using setCookie then HasCookie value is true.

Comment: If I am clearing the cookies from the browser manually then it is working fine but when I am trying to fetch the cookie from app, CookieManager is not showing any cookies.  I have tried these
CookieManager.Instance.RemoveSessionCookie();
CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookie();

Comment: I think it might take some time until the cookies are in sync. Could you also try CookieManager.Instance.Flush() and wait a few seconds after calling the CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookie(); again.

Comment: I found this post, seems to be using your library and tackling the same issue: https://mallibone.com/post/xamarin-oidc-logout

Comment: What I understood from it is that you have to ask the user to log out from the browser, you cannot log out by yourself because we don't have access to the browser's cookies. If you want to achieve the behaviour you mentioned, I think you need a different approach. What I know it will work because I did it some time ago is using a CustomWebView to open the login page and you have access to cookies in there. What it might work as well is using the Xamarin.Essentials Web Authenticator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=ios